Should the OpenMP proc_bind clause always force the requested binding?
(Test code is here, for those who want to read it, or play with it).
It includes a parallel region with an omp_proc_bind(close) clause, as well as a preceding one without. Inside each parallel region it prints the actual thread affinity, to show whether the requested binding has been achieved. (Sorry, this assumes Linux, since I go low and call sched_getaffinity to investigate what is going on).
Consider these executions of the code:-
% OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out
omp_get_max_threads() = 4
OMP_PLACES="UNDEFINED", omp_get_num_places() = 0
OMP_PROC_BIND="UNDEFINED", omp_proc_bind() = false
omp_get_num_threads() = 4
0: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
1: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
2: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
3: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}

Forcing proc_bind(close)
omp_get_num_threads() = 4
0: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
1: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
2: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}
3: omp_get_place_num() = -1, {0-287}

That shows that the explicit proc_bind clause has been ignored!
Whereas, if we force a binding using the envirables, then the explicit proc_bind clause is respected, and changes the pre-existing binding:-
% OMP_PROC_BIND=spread OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out
omp_get_max_threads() = 4
OMP_PLACES="UNDEFINED", omp_get_num_places() = 288
OMP_PROC_BIND="spread", omp_proc_bind() = spread
omp_get_num_threads() = 4
0: omp_get_place_num() = 0, {0}
1: omp_get_place_num() = 72, {72}
2: omp_get_place_num() = 144, {144}
3: omp_get_place_num() = 216, {216}

Forcing proc_bind(close)
omp_get_num_threads() = 4
0: omp_get_place_num() = 0, {0}
1: omp_get_place_num() = 1, {1}
2: omp_get_place_num() = 2, {2}
3: omp_get_place_num() = 3, {3}

AFAICS the OpenMP standard (here), requires that the proc_bind clause is respected irrespective of the setting of envirables:-

If the parallel directive has a proc_bind clause then the binding policy specified by the proc_bind clause overrides the policy specified by the first element of the bind-var ICV.

However both GCC and LLVM seem to ignore the explicit proc_bind clause unless there is already binding going on as a reasult of the envirable being set.
This seems wrong to me. Am I missing something?

OK, I found the answer, and it is "The proc_bind clause can be ignored if binding has been requested via an envirable."
The route to that is

"If bind-var is not set to false then the proc_bind clause overrides the value of the first element of the bind-var ICV; otherwise, the proc_bind clause has no effect." (Here in the standard).
In the table of ICV initialisation rules (here), we have that the bind-var initial value is "Implementation defined".

So, implementations are allowed to make the default for the bind-var be false,and, as a result, ignore proc_bind clauses.
This seems somewhat dubious to me, since it means that one can write code that is explicit about what it wants, and then have that be ignored at runtime, and, even worse when debugging, be ignored sometimes and not others, or with one compiler but not another!

Wouldn't it make sense to have OMP_PROC_BIND=true as the most basic thing to be explicit that the user actually wants the threads to be pinned and use OMP_PROC_BIND=false to request to ignore the proc_bind clause in the code? At least that would be a rational explanation of what we have put into the OpenMP specification.

I think my proposal would be to introduce another provider-bond state, something like "explicit" (or "respect-clause') which would be the defined default, and would require that the explicit proc_bind clause is respected, but says nothing about what happens elsewhere.

Another possible solution (though maybe slightly less user-friendly) solution would be to add an omp_set_proc_bind(bindval) function. However I see this is less friendly because it requires code change, and makes it harder to force the use/non-use of binding easily for benchmarking. Simply changing the default value to be defined, and respect what the code asked for, requires no changes to code, and still allows complete control via the envirable. (It is making some currently undefined behaviour into defined behaviour, which is a standard compatible change!)
